# NSFetchRequest with no duplications by parameter

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a simply `BWWishlistBook` entity which has a property `BWBook`. One `BWBook` may belong to **many** `BWWishlistBook`s and one `BWWishlistBook` always have only one `BWBook`.

Now I have a `NSFetchRequest` for `BWWishlistBook`:

```
let fetchReguest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BWWishlistBook")
```

I need to avoid to fetch wishlist books with the same book inside. is it possible? How to setup predicate then? `BWBook` has an unique `id` property.

In MySQL this is DISTINCT. What is in CoreData?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which `BWBook` for which you want to fetch `BWWishlistBook` the easiest (and most performant way) is the fetch it by the relationship on the `BWBook`.

Maybe something along the lines of

```
wishlist = bwBook.bwWishlistBooks
```

Answer (score 0):

[-returnsDistinctResults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/returnsDistinctResults)

```
/* Returns/sets if the fetch request returns only distinct values for the fields specified by propertiesToFetch. 
   This value is only used for NSDictionaryResultType. 
   Defaults to NO. */

@available(iOS 3.0, *)
public var returnsDistinctResults: Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a fetch on `BWBook` with a predicate of `wishlist.count != 0`.

Now you will have a list of books (all distinct) and all of them will have at least one wishlist associated with them.

Now you can just display the first wishlist from each book and you will have a list of wish lists with distinct books.